# Segmentation Fault from accessing a struct

Tags: c, shell, syntax, segmentation-fault

I'm getting a segmentation fault (cores dumped) fault as a result of this code:

```
char **getPipedCmds(Pgm *p){

  if (p == NULL) {
  } else {
    char **pipedP = p->next->pgmlist; // I'm the line where the seg fault occurs.
    return pipedP;
  }
}
```

And here are the struct definitions, probably pretty useful here...

```
typedef struct c {
  char **pgmlist;
  struct c *next;
} Pgm;

typedef struct node { 
  Pgm  *pgm;
  ...
} Command;
```

So, is there anyway to get the data I need from  `p->next->pgmlist` without getting a seg fault?

Comment: well p->next is null or pointing anywhere

Comment: You've established that `p != NULL`, but what about `p->next != NULL`? You should always know if a pointer is `NULL` before you dereference it.

Comment: Not all control paths return a value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a common error and you should really try to learn using a debugging tool.

As far as I can see, you do not check if `p->next` exist or not before accessing it. If it's NULL, that would be undefined behavior and you get a segmentation fault. If it's a random value, you should initialize your structure appropriately when allocating memory, in this case, `next` to NULL.

By adding these few lines you should be safe.

```
if (p != NULL) {

    if (p->next != NULL) {
        char **pipedP = p->next->pgmlist; // I'm the line where the seg fault occurs.
        return pipedP;
    }

}
```

Some few tips,

1. When you allocate memory for a structure, set it to 0 (ie. `memset(mem, 0, sizeof mem)`)
2. When accessing a pointer, always check if its NULL or not, otherwise you would be generating Segmentation fault like here
3. When your program has been killed, you can do backtrace why your system killed it by using `coredumpctl gdb` (it will take the last dump generated on your computer and put it on gdb to debug)